Sequelize: insert into join table
Tables: Users, Categories, Users_Categories
Let's say one user already exists (user_id = 1) and one category already exists (category_id = 1).
Now I want to "link" them through the Users_Categories join table.
How to do that with Sequelize (v6)?
The association between tables is done that way:

User.belongsToMany(Category, {through: User_Category});


Category.belongsToMany(User, {through: User_Category});


I can use a raw query with sequelize.query(...) but I wanted to know if there's another way to achieve this.
